# Gather data from multiple Excel worksheets, and display results on new sheet in the same workbook?

Tags: excel

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am trying to determine the number of times certain words (ie. PTSD, School, Education etc.)appear in Column (A) Rows 1-32  in 81 different worksheets of the same excel workbook. I want to then display the results on a new sheet (82) in the same workbook. the goal is to display the top search terms used.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to illustrate your attempts so far.  You'll be more likely to get some help.

Comment: all i have tried are the =countif & countifs with no luck, as I am not sure what to do. It is to daunting of a task to do by hand as there are 81 sheets spaning 32 rows per sheet, in no particular order. What i did was write a Macro to pull data from my website and the macro added the data to 81 different worksheets in the same workbook. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: =countif('1:81'!,A1:A32,"PTSD") here is a formula that I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested by me (82 sheets? - no way!) but the principle works. Group all your 82 sheets. Put the following formulae in Sheet82 in a column that is not occupied in any spreadsheet (say C1 ...):

> =COUNTIF(A1:A32,"PTSD")
>   =COUNTIF(A1:A32,"School")
>   =COUNTIF(A1:A32,"Education")

Ungroup and in `D1` put `=SUM('1:81'!C1)`. Copy down as required.

Would be neater (but more complex) to use variables rather than hard coding `PTSD` etc but there can't be too many if each list is 32 items and some are duplicated anyway.

Comment: Okay so I tried =Countif(A1:A32,"PTSD") in C1 returned result = 0 (not possible as it is displayed several times). I then in cell D1 put =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet81!C1) and was prompted to select a workbook (the work book i want to use is the one with all the data). I want to count how many times the word PTSD is displayed across all 81 sheets rows 1-32. is it not possible to do this?

Comment: they are named 1-81, with sheet 82 being named 25 top searches 7-12 - 7-13.

Comment: That worked great thank you so much you saved me hrs of work.

Comment: Now can i pull terms like VFW if the full text of some cells reads VFW Post... I jsut want the program to fund all terms VFW instead of having to add (post) to the search criteria?

Comment: does the * allow it to search for the term specified before the *